# Function returns correct value when printed but fails assertion

Tags: java, assert, assertion

I need to write a code for a pension plan.

The main function is such

```
double pensionTarget = 240000;
double currentSaving = 0;
double annualSalary = 40000;
double monthlySaving = 0.1;
double interestRate = 0.04;

PensionPlanner fp = new PensionPlanner(pensionTarget, currentSaving,
        annualSalary, monthlySaving, interestRate);

System.out.println("Example: Test case 1 working months: " + fp.getWorkingMonth());
assert fp.getWorkingMonth() == 368: "Failed test case 1: Expected working months to be 368, but got " + fp.getWorkingMonth();
```

The getWorkingMonth() function in the PensionPlanner class is as such

```
public int getWorkingMonth() {
    double Saving = monthlySaving * (annualSalary / 12);
    int months = 0;

    while (currentSaving < pensionTarget) {
        currentSaving += Saving + (currentSaving * (interestRate / 12));
        months++;
    }

    return months;
}
```

I keep failing the assertion test.

I have debugged the code and made sure the values are calculated correctly. In the main function this line, does give the expected number of months,

```
System.out.println("Example: Test case 1 working months: " + fp.getWorkingMonth());
```

But it fails the assertion and the function getWorkingMonth() returns a value of 0 in this line

```
assert fp.getWorkingMonth() == 368: "Failed test case 1: Expected working months to be 368, but got " + fp.getWorkingMonth();
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Note that the `assert` statement is not meant to write tests, but to write inline assertions to check invariants of your code. If you want to write assertions in tests, you should use the appropriate assertion methods from your test framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the instance field `currentSaving` in the method, so calling `getWorkingMonth()` a second time will return `0`.

Avoid doing this if you want consistent results. You could use a local variable instead.

```java
public int getWorkingMonth() {
    double Saving = monthlySaving * (annualSalary / 12);
    int months = 0;
    double curr = currentSaving;
    while (curr < pensionTarget) {
        curr += Saving + (curr * (interestRate / 12));
        months++;
    }
    return months;
}
```